# udp traffic with Iperf for haproxy

Tags: python, docker, haproxy, iperf

I'm working on my personal project on "performance evaluation" of Haproxy using Docker Container. I'm programming with Python and uses iperf for traffic generation.

I created several Docker containers as clients and servers. The clients are supposed to send udp traffic to servers via Haproxy container which acts as a load balancer.

The issue is when I try to send udp traffic from clients to servers, Haproxy refuses the connexions.
I did not find in the official documentation how to bind or listen to UDP port.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Here is a copy of my haproxy.cfg.

`global 
 quiet
 nbproc 4 
 daemon
listen tcp_haproxy 172.17.4.230:5001
balance roundrobin
server server0 172.17.4.227:5001
server server1 172.17.4.228:5001
server server2 172.17.4.229:5001`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I read it, this question is more about UDP load balancing than Docker. Please feel free to correct me if I misread the question.

You probably won't like this answer, but here goes. **HAProxy does not support UDP**. The [official homepage](http://www.haproxy.org/) describes HAProxy as *TCP and HTTP* proxy explicitly (by implication, this means "no UDP"). There are also [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/669441/load-balancing-dns-servers-udp-tcp) regarding the topic of UDP load balancing, which also discusses and quickly dismisses HAProxy.

Since I don't like "that's not possible, deal with it" as an answer myself, let's have a look at alternatives.

1. Some resources that ask about UDP load balancing end up recommending [IPVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Virtual_Server) as load balancer. It's part of the Linux kernel, which makes it a bad solution if you're looking for something based on Docker. If that's not a deal breaker for you, there a [short example on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Virtual_Server#Examples) that can be adjusted to your scenario with three UDP servers:

   ```
   ipvsadm -A -u 172.17.4.230:5001 -s rr
   ipvsadm -a -u 172.17.4.230:5001 -r 172.17.4.227:5001 -m
   ipvsadm -a -u 172.17.4.230:5001 -r 172.17.4.228:5001 -m
   ipvsadm -a -u 172.17.4.230:5001 -r 172.17.4.229:5001 -m
   ```
2. A quick Google search turns up alternative open-source solutions like [Pen](http://siag.nu/pen/). Might also be worth a look?
3. Sure you can't use TCP instead? ;)

Comment: Yes it is about UDP load balancing than Docker. I used Docker container as an alternative to Virtual Machines...
You are all right. I appreciate your answer.
1) It is just about performance evaluation between balance and haproxy. 
2) thanks for the link.
3 ) I need to compare balance and haproxy under TCP mode and UDP mode, since haproxy does not support udp load balancing, it is okay.
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2016 the best solution to this problem is currently Nginx >=1.9.13 :

https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/

You can configure HA and health checks for UDP upstreams just like you would a back end TCP reverse proxy. For my project we implemented a solution using a custom container from the base Nginx container (which may be relevant to OP's docker use case), which can be found here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/