# Haproxy loadbalancing udp server

Tags: haproxy

Does haproxy supports udp loadbalancing?

We're just using a simple python script on backend server which will be listening on specific port for the udp packects.

Answer (score 6):

[HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) is for TCP/HTTP and UNIX sockets as well: "…

> This is alternative to the TCP listening port. Haproxy will then receive UNIX connections on the socket

…" but apparently it has no support of UDP except for logging purposes.

[Nginx is an option](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-udp-load-balancing/) you can consider though.

Comment: Nginx is an option if you already have Nginx. 
If you need to install something that does only UDP load-balancing, I'd suggest something like "pen" which is less convoluted, and it does not come with a lot of features that you might not need.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Haproxy doesn't support udp load balancing.  See this question for more details: [udp traffic with Iperf for haproxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255780/udp-traffic-with-iperf-for-haproxy)

Answer (score 1):

Haproxy 2.3 allows proxying of syslog UDP. Thus one could bind an UDP socket only to proxy syslog.